# Static method throwing common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, map, static

This is the Exception I am getting

> common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

I'm getting a Exception thrown while running a unit test. I'm looking at it now for 2 hours and don't see this issue.

This is the Method Call:

```
Map<ContractorApiUtils.OperationEnum, List<ContractorApiUtils.FileDto>> processBatches = ContratorAPI.getProcessingBatchMap();
```

This is the static method

```
@testvisible
private static Map<ContractorApiUtils.OperationEnum, List<ContractorApiUtils.FileDto>> getProcessingBatchMap(){
     Map<ContractorApiUtils.OperationEnum, List<ContractorApiUtils.FileDto>> batches = 
        new Map<ContractorApiUtils.OperationEnum, List<ContractorApiUtils.FileDto>>();
        batches.put(ContractorApiUtils.OperationEnum.C, new List<ContractorApiUtils.FileDto>());
        batches.put(ContractorApiUtils.OperationEnum.R, new List<ContractorApiUtils.FileDto>());
        batches.put(ContractorApiUtils.OperationEnum.U, new List<ContractorApiUtils.FileDto>());
        batches.put(ContractorApiUtils.OperationEnum.D, new List<ContractorApiUtils.FileDto>());
    return batches;
}
```

Anyone got an idea? When I run it from anonymous, it works perfectly.

Comment: Is your ContractorApiUtils.OperationEnum reading from any custom settings?

Comment: nope- A simple Enum defined in a class

Comment: What's FileDto?

Comment: A simple Data transfer object class

Comment: @user853710 Any clues if you capture the full debug log when the test is running? The error looks a bit odd. If it was Apex I'd expect it to be a System.NullPointerException. Is there a corresponding GACK message or similar?

Comment: This is all I get. I also tried to debug line by line, ... The items are not even being put into the map. and it breaks  on the return.  Is it possible that it does not like the variable name "batches?"

Comment: At least as far as I'm concerned, I'm pretty sure you're reading the logs wrong. I don't see any way this could be crashing. We're probably going to need to see some surrounding code.

Comment: this simply does not make sense. I coppied the creation of the map instead of calling the method, .... and it works. no exception, nothing.
sometimes SF simply makes no sense. retarted